# log file with insert - how to easly combine column name with inserted value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Has anybody a good solution how to combine column name with inserted value from prepared INSERT SQL?

I have log file. In this log file I have INSERT query. This query contains over 100 columns for example:

```
INSERT INTO tab
 (col_001, col_002, col_003, col_004, col_005, col_006, col_007, col_008, col_009, col_010)
VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c,,,', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j');
```

Do you have any ideas how to easly combine column name to value like below:

```
col_001 = 'a'
col_002 = 'b'
col_003 = 'c,,,'
col_004 = 'd'
col_005 = 'e'
col_006 = 'f'
col_007 = 'g'
col_008 = 'h'
col_009 = 'i'
col_010 = 'j
```

Lets imagine that I need to find what value will be inserted in column col_067.

Thanks.

Comment: Reposting a [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494056/insert-combine-the-columns-with-a-value-from-log) question isn't the right thing to do here. There is an [edit] feature... Doing this wastes the time of the people you asked for help from. I suggest this being an XY Problem again. Fix your design, fix your problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have a *log file* - ok, is that a text file? Are you asking how to parse the data in a text file? Or is this actually data in a SQL Server database and you're referring to a table? If so you'll need to split the values into two groups of multiple rows and join them. A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with actual table definitions would be beneficial.

Comment: *"you can only vote or close request?"* See [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/2029983). If you looked at your prior question, which is an exact duplicate of this, you'll see I didn't vote to close it... If a question is closed the voters are made public. Downvotes never are, but just because I was first to comment doesn't mean I've voted; the 2 are completely separate actions.

Comment: @lptr your idea is nice :) Thanks :) I LOVE it :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `unpivot` for convert column to row

```
select colname,
       colvalue
from tab
unpivot
(
  colvalue
  for colname in (col_001, col_002, col_003, col_004, col_005, col_006, col_007, col_008, col_009, col_010)
) unpiv;
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=46f279bfc5c6133868878ca097d914cb)